# Can I use different networks for inbound and outbound traffic?

Tags: configuration, network-configuration

My relay server is connected to two networks: a DSL with decent download but poor upload speed and a symmetric fiber connection which has a lot of contention in the download direction but has plenty of upload to spare.

Can I set up the relay so that incoming traffic uses the DSL and outgoing uses the fiber? How would I configure it?

That would maximize the bandwidth I can give the relay and seems like it could be good for the Tor network because traffic would be routed through two different ISPs.

Comment: Do you mean, using two distinct IP addresses for the Tor relay?

Comment: @blau, well, yes, that would probably be implied.

Comment: There's an option in the `torrc` file for outgoing traffic (OutboundBindAddress), but I haven't found anything for specifying inbound traffic. If it's as easy as InboundBindAddress, I'll be amazed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved by using the [`OutboundBindAddress`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#OutboundBindAddress) configuration option. For example in your torrc:

```
ORPort 1.2.3.4:9001
OutboundBindAddress 4.3.2.1
```

Note, however, that if a client connects to `1.2.3.4`, response cells will be sent back down that connection, the responses won't be sent down a new outbound connection from `4.3.2.1`

From the manual:

> **OutboundBindAddress** *IP*
>
> Make all outbound connections originate from the IP address specified. This is only useful when you have multiple network interfaces, and you want all of Tor’s outgoing connections to use a single one. This option may be used twice, once with an IPv4 address and once with an IPv6 address. This setting will be ignored for connections to the loopback addresses (127.0.0.0/8 and ::1).

Comment: So what does it mean for bandwidth? A small trickle up the ORPort address and down the OutboudBindAddress, but most data going the directions I was looking for?